# MySQL Function Returns Column Value

Tags: mysql

With the help of StackOverflow I have a MySQL query that works. After making a few changes it returns `zip` and `distance`. I been trying to make a Function to set parameters for the given lat and lng values and return the zip from the other table. However the query returns two values, I only need one.

```
SELECT loc.zip,(((ACOS(SIN((lat*PI()/180)) * SIN((`latitude`*PI()/180))+COS((lat*PI()/180)) * COS((`latitude`*pi()/180)) * COS(((lng - `longitude`)*PI()/180))))*180/PI())*60*1.1515) AS `distance` FROM geov1.zcta loc HAVING distance < 5 LIMIT 1;
```

So far this is what I have as my Function:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE lat VARCHAR(15);
DECLARE lng VARCHAR(15);
DECLARE zip BIGINT;

SET zip = SELECT loc.zip,(((ACOS(SIN((lat*PI()/180)) * SIN((`latitude`*PI()/180))+COS((lat*PI()/180)) * COS((`latitude`*pi()/180)) * COS(((lng - `longitude`)*PI()/180))))*180/PI())*60*1.1515) AS `distance` FROM geov1.zcta loc HAVING distance < 5 LIMIT 1;

RETURN zip;

END
```

This does not work, give me and error that there is some wrong in line 10 which is this:

```
`longitude`)*PI()/180))))*180/PI())*60*1.1515) AS `distance` FROM geov1.zcta loc HAVING distance < 5 LIMIT 1;
```

At this point I am at a loss, I just need to have the query return the zip with the given coordinates. Thank you for the help.

Comment: You may need to replace "distance < 5" by "(((ACOS(SIN((lat*PI()/180)) * SIN((`latitude`*PI()/180))+COS((lat*PI()/180)) * COS((`latitude`*pi()/180)) * COS(((lng - `longitude`)*PI()/180))))*180/PI())*60*1.1515) < 5"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your SELECT statement returns two values, then you should use SELECT statement with INTO clause, e.g. -

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE a, b INT;
  SELECT MIN(column1), MAX(column1) INTO a,b FROM table;
END
```